# How does one obtain and install KSokoban?

Tags: installation, games

How does one obtain and install KSokoban on Ubuntu 12.10? It used to be there in KDE 3, but is gone now.

Comment: Did you look here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ksokoban/ ? (No personal knowledge; just mentioned it because you didn't mention where you looked for it.)

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't looked there. But under the "files" section there's only a Windows installer and under the "code" section there's a bunch of stuff which looks nebulous, with no instructions on how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, KSokoban hasn't been ported to KDE4. Searching in kde.org I could find a few things:

[The KDE (Legacy) Games Center](http://games.kde.org/old/kde_tactics.php) says:

> KSokoban
>
> ...
>
> Version:  v0.4.2 - **KDE 3.x**

That's the [only mention to the game in games.kde.org](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&lr=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&q=site%3agames.kde.org%20sokoban).

Its [source code](https://projects.kde.org/projects/playground/games/ksokoban/repository) doesn't seem to have been changed in years.

There's a bug in bugs.kde.org asking to port it, but its status is "unconfirmed": [Bug 167910 - Port KSokoban to KDE4](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=167910). In that bug is mentioned that KSokoban was being worked on, with the name Magazynier, but I guess it was never released. I couldn't find anything with that name in the repos, and its [source code](http://websvn.kde.org/trunk/playground/games/magazynier/) hasn't been touched in more than 2 years. A [search for magazynier](https://projects.kde.org/search?q=magazynier) in projects.kde.org shows no results. In [this thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.kde.devel.games/7013) the author says:

> Well, magazynier, which is a sokoban game for KDE4, has a chance to be included in KDE SC 4.5, though it still
>   needs some work.

But that seems to be the last.

Other [bugs for ksokoban](https://bugs.kde.org/buglist.cgi?bug_status=__all__&content=ksokoban&list_id=408395&query_format=specific&order=changeddate%20DESC,relevance%20DESC&query_based_on=) are closed with unmaintained status.

Other than that, there are some mailing list and forum threads that mention it, saying that there is no KSokoban in KDE4.

---

The project [ksokoban in SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ksokoban/), mentioned by @vasa1 in a comment, says it "requires KDE4 and Qt4", but its [only file release](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ksokoban/files/?source=navbar) as of now is a Windows program.

Answer (score 0):

KSokoban is referred to as [Magic Sokoban](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/quantal/magicsokoban/) in Ubuntu 11.10, 12.04 and 12.10.

Comment: Actually, that's a different program from KSokoban (which can be seen [here](http://games.kde.org/old/kde_tactics.php)). However, it is an excellent alternative.

Comment: But that resembles almost same as we have in Ubuntu apps directory. precise it does the same thing but has Colorful and 3D realistic visualization.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'll try to rewrite it for KDE 4 myself. [Here](http://www.cmi.ac.in/~prateek/ksokoban-ng/) is the result. (This is probably a terrible way of distributing it, but I have no idea how to go about packaging, and most of the tutorials/documentation I found online was not helpful.)

Answer (score -1):

While ksokoban might not be available, SokoMind is a very similar replacement:

```
wget http://archive.org/download/SokoMind20_1020/sokomd34.zip
unzip sokomd34.zip SokoMind.exe
wine SokoMind.exe
```

Comment: Note that wine and games don't always behave well.  It's also possible the OP wants a natively-run game rather than a Windows game (and therefore won't want to install wine and such).